# How to execute EMR step that loads more scripts from s3?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I want to execute a shell script as a step on EMR that loads a tarball, unzips it and runs the script inside. I chose this setup to stay as vendor-agnostic as possible.
My script is

```
#!/bin/sh
aws s3 cp s3://path_to_my_bucket/name_of.tar.gz .
tar -xzf name_of.tar.gz
. main_script.sh
```

Where `main_script.sh` is part of the tarball along with a number of other packages, scripts and config files.

If I run this script as a Hadoop user on the master node, everything works as intended. Added as a step via the [command-runner.jar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html), I get errors, no matter what I try.

What I tried so far (and the errors):

- running the script as above (file not found "main_script.sh")
- hardcoding the path to be the Hadoop users home directory (permission denied on `main_script.sh`)
- dynamically getting the path where script lives (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within)) and giving this path as an argument for the `tar -C` option and invoking `main_script.sh` explicitly from this path (another permission denied on `main_script.sh`)

**What is the proper way of loading a bash script into the master node and executing it?**

As a bonus, I am wondering why the `command-runner.jar` is set up so different from the spark step, which runs as the Hadoop user in the Hadoop user directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use script-runner.jar with region

JAR location : s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar

Arguments : s3://your_bucket/your_shell_script.sh

Refer below link for more info
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html